# How does scipy.stats.weibull_min.fit produce its initial guess?

Tags: python, scipy, weibull

I was looking at the source code for [scipy.stats.weibull_min.fit](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.weibull_min.html). This can be found at https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.3.0/scipy/stats/_distn_infrastructure.py#L2157.  This function returns three fitted parameters. E.g.:

```
import numpy
numpy.random.seed(4)
from scipy.stats import weibull_min
samples = weibull_min.rvs(0.4,  loc=0, scale=1.5, size = 10)
weibull_min.fit(samples)
(0.44243114317044474, 0.01717442938653987, 10.61124981692991)
```

It seems to find the maximum likelihood by calling [scipy.optimize.fmin](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fmin.html) as indicated by:

```
vals = optimizer(func, x0, args=(ravel(data),), disp=0)
```

> But this requires an initial guess x0. What is this set to? This seems
>   to be the relevant [line in the source code](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.3.0/scipy/stats/_distn_infrastructure.py#L2130) but it doesn't help me
>   answer the question.
>
> In short, what is the full equivalent line of code using scipy.optimize.fmin that  corresponds to weibull_min.fit(samples)?

Comment: Why are you using numpy for seeding instead of the inbuilt random module?

Comment: @MilkyWay90 No good reason. I don’t understand which seed affects which functions.  Does inbuilt random seed control scipy randomness too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems `fit` calls [`_fitstart(data)`](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.3.0/scipy/stats/_distn_infrastructure.py#L2261), and the result of that is saved in `args` which is then passed to [`_reduce_func`](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.3.0/scipy/stats/_distn_infrastructure.py#L2266) (always +- 2 arguments at the end of the `args` list).

In [`_fitstart`](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.3.0/scipy/stats/_distn_infrastructure.py#L2097)  `_fit_loc_scale_support(data,...)` is called, which again calls [`fit_loc_scale(data,...)`](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.3.0/scipy/stats/_distn_infrastructure.py#L2356) which is where the magic seems to happend: Basically the mean and standard deviation are computed, which are in then "postprocessed" `_fit_loc_scale_support`. Then a `1` is prependend for all other parameters (in this case one). So these two parameters are basically used as an initial guess for the location and scaling parameters of the distributions, plus this `1` for the first "shape parameter".

Comment: For the example in the question, is it possible to tell explicitly what these initial guesses are?

Comment: I used `numpy.random.seed(4)` as `numpy.seed` doesn't seem to exist. Then I get `x0==[1.0, -4.875442806278793, 16.482864588854564]` (It is easy to do with the debugger of PyCharm, just set a breakpoint before the optimizer is called.)

Comment: That's fascinating. Starting with negative value for loc does not look sensible at all.